# How to keep an applied style on a button after click

Tags: wpf

The whole situation looks like that:

There are several buttons on a View in a StackPanel. The first of them should be chosen by default. When the button is chosen it's backgroung must be of green color, the other (not chosen) button's background must be of blue color.

Is it possible to implement such a behaviour without implementation some logic in a ViewModel?

update 1. I talk about Buttons not ToggleButtons

Comment: button or toggleButton?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an `Style` setting the property that you want to change when the user click on it.

You cand find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770125/how-do-i-style-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

A `Button` cannot be selected, or 'chosen' as you call it. It does not have an `IsSelected` property. If you want that behaviour, then you will need to use a `ToggleButton`, or maybe even a `RadioButton` that is `Style`d to look like a regular `Button`:

Add this `Style` to your `Resources` section:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="3.5" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="3" Background="Blue" Padding="10,0,10,2">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then you can use `RadioButton`s that look like `Button`s and meet your requirements:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton Content="One" />
    <RadioButton Content="Two" />
    <RadioButton Content="Three" />
    <RadioButton Content="Four" />
</StackPanel>
```