# How intercept onMouseOver on the Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

I have a WPF Application in C#. When I run my application it dynamically creates a Button with Background Image.

This is the sample code:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Width = 130;
button.Height = 190;
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+@"\Images\nao_grigio.png")));
brush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
buttonCoppia.Background = brush;
button.Background = brush;
```

It works, so when I pass on the Button with mouse the image is changed with default button image.

How I fixed it?

---

I have copy your code in XAML file. So my code is

```
<Window x:Name="idWindows" x:Class="MemoryGame.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageSource" UriSource="Resources\nao_grigio.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MouseOverImage" UriSource="Resources\nao_grigio.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MousePressed" UriSource="Resources\nao_grigio.png"/>
    <Style x:Key="BtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Gd">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey= ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Gd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey= MouseOverImage}" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Button x:Key="MyStyle" Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Memory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="320,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="40"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelTime" Content="Tempo : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="628,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.211,-0.115"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelSecondi" Content="0 sec" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,136,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelNumeroErrori" Content="Numero Errori : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="628,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelNumeroErrori_Cont" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,178,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.125,-0.692"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelNumeroRisposteNonDate" Content="Risposte non date : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="628,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelNumeroRisposteNonDate_Cont" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,220,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.125,-0.692"/>
    <Grid x:Name="gridToken"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="72,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>
</Grid>
```

in MainWindow.xaml.cs i have this:

```
 Button button = new Button();
     ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+@"\Images\nao_grigio.png")));
   brush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
   buttonCoppia.Background = brush;
   button.Background = brush;
   button.Style = this.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
```

But it not works.

Comment: I have see in the C# Form application there is this property "UseVisualStyleBackgroundColor", if this property is UseVisualStyleBackgroundColor=false; i solved my problem, but in WPF Application there isn't this property. How i fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write a style for your control, so it keeps the background image during its lifecycle (mouse hover/exit/click/focused/etc...). It's actually not very hard once you get used to it, so no need to be afraid :)

Those links should get you covered in no time:

[How do I style Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770125/how-do-i-style-buttons)

http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageSource" UriSource="DefaultImage.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MouseOverImage" UriSource="MouseOverImage.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MousePressed" UriSource="MousePressed.png"/>

    <Style x:Key="BtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Gd">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey= ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Gd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey= MouseOverImage}" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.Pressed" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Gd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey= MousePressed}" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


<Button Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
```